# Redirect uri not working

Tags: symfony, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the oauth google authentication in symfony2 with hwi oauth bundle. I added the button and the popup open and succesfull autenticate the user and then execute my signinCallback function in javascript. The problem is that i need register the user in the database after the login action, so I configured the redirect_uri for that reason. I test the action with a succesfull autentication with github, without popup, just creating a `<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?scope=user:email&client_id=MY_ID">Click here</a>`, and that redirect to that page and after autentication redirect me to the correct redirect uri. The problem with google is that after a succesfull atentication only call the javascript function, not to the configured uri. Is there a way to make the google autentication in the same way of github?. I also try in the signinCallback function call `document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "google"}) }}"` , but get some error related to required parameters of course .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps someone that's how I solved:

```
function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['access_token']) {
            // Properly authorized
            // Hide the button
            document.getElementById('customBtn').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
            document.location = "{{ url("hwi_oauth_service_redirect", {service: "google"}) }}";
        } else if (authResult['error']) {
            // If error
            // console.log('There was an error: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
    }
```